# way to figure out differential equation from limited information

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been stuck on this for days.

Given $y(0) = 23000$, $y(5) = 0$, and $ y' = 0.07y - N$, how would I solve for N.

I've managed to get to $y = Ce^{0.07x} + \frac{N}{0.07} $, but I can't figure out how to get either N or C, since I know once I have one I can get the other.

Could anyone explain how to get to the answer? I care more about how to get there rather than the answer itself.

Comment: Hi, Do you mean from $y^1 = 0.07y - N
$ this $y'= 0.07y - N$?

Comment: (I assume $y^1$ is the first derivative $y'$.) You have $y(0)$ and $y(5)$ given, and using your function, you can express both as combinations $\alpha C + \beta N$. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Khosrotash I did mean Y prime. and Toffomat I can't figure out what C or N are, and need them to have a complete equation

Comment: Solve the system
\begin{align}
y(0)&=Ce^{0.07\times 0}+\frac{N}{0.07}=23000, \\
y(5)&=Ce^{0.07\times 5}+\frac{N}{0.07}=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you Gonçalo, that helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the solution as $y = Ce^{0.07x} + \frac{N}{0.07}
$ so put $y(0)=23000, \ y(5)=0$into it
$$y(0)= Ce^{0.07(0)} + \frac{N}{0.07}=23000\\y(5)= Ce^{0.07(5)} + \frac{N}{0.07}=0
$$so $$\begin{cases}Ce^{0.07(0)} + \frac{N}{0.07}=2300 \\Ce^{0.07(5)} + \frac{N}{0.07}=0\end{cases}$$and
$$\begin{cases}C + \frac{N}{0.07}=2300 \\Ce^{0.35} + \frac{N}{0.07}=0\end{cases}\\c(1-e^{0.35})=23000-0 \to c=\frac{23000}{1-e^{0.35}}$$ can you take over?

Comment: Why bother solving for $C$?  It's $N$ you want.  Subtract $C e^{0.35} + \frac{N}{0.07} = 0$ from  $e^{0.35} \left(C + \frac{N}{0.07}\right) = 2300 e^{0.35}$ and ...